# Java: How to fill placeholders in a text with Map<String,String>?

Tags: java, string, hashmap, mapping, placeholder

I am working with a code where I want fill several string place holders with another strings. This is the example text I have used to test my code.

```
String myStr = "Media file %s of size %s has been approved"
```

This is how I fill the place holders. Since I expect to use several place holders I have used java Map<>.

```
Map<String, String> propMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
propMap.put("file name","20mb");
String newNotification = createNotification(propMap);
```

I used following method to create the string.

```
public String createNotification(Map<String, String> properties){
    String message = ""; 
    message = String.format(myStr, properties);

    return message;
}
```

How do I replace two of '%s' with "file name" and "20mb"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several ways finally found a good solution. Place holders must be like this [placeholder] .

```
public String createNotification(){
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[(.+?)\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(textTemplate);
    HashMap<String,String> replacementValues = new HashMap<String,String>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String replacement = replacementValues.get(matcher.group(1));
        builder.append(textTemplate.substring(i, matcher.start()));
        if (replacement == null){ builder.append(matcher.group(0)); }      
        else { builder.append(replacement); }     
        i = matcher.end();
    }
    builder.append(textTemplate.substring(i, textTemplate.length()));
    return builder.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your approach to [String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) is wrong.

It expects a variable amount of objects to replace the placeholders as the second argument, not a map. To group them all together, you can use an array or a list.

```
String format = "Media file %s of size %s has been approved";

Object[] args = {"file name", "20mb"};
String newNotification = String.format(format, args);
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not what a Map is intended to do.
What you add is an entry `"file name" -> "20 mb"`, which basically means the property "file name" has the value "20 mb". What you are trying to do with it is "maintain a tuple of items".

Note that the formatting string has a fixed amount of placeholder; you want a data structure that contains exactly the same amount of items; so essentially an array or a `List`.

Thus, what you want to have is

```
public String createNotification(String[] properties) {
    assert(properties.length == 2); // you might want to really check this, you will run into problems if it's false
    return String.format("file %s has size %s", properties);
}
```

If you want to create notifications of all items in a map, you need to do something like this:

```
Map<String,String> yourMap = //...
for (Entry<String,String> e : yourMap) {
    System.out.println(createNotification(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this formatting using var-args:

```
    String myStr = "Media file %s of size %s has been approved";

    String newNotification = createNotification(myStr, "file name", "20mb");

    System.out.println(newNotification);
```

Pass var-args in `createNotification` method, here is the code:

```
public static String createNotification(String myStr, String... strings){
    String message = ""; 
    message=String.format(myStr, strings[0], strings[1]);

    return message;
}
```

Comment: But in each case there are different number of strings to be replaced. Therefore I don't think this can be used.

Comment: @Sandu_prass this is for the given string "Media file %s of size %s has been approved", we can make it dynamic by making some changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think `%s` is Python’s grammar to place holder, can’t use this in Java environment; and your method `createNotification()` defined needs two parameters, can’t only give one.

Comment: %s _can_ be used in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax